# How to fetch data of multiple HTML tables through Web Scraping in Java

Tags: java, html, csv, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape the data of a website and to some extents I succeed in my goal. But, there is a problem that the web page I am trying to scrape have got multiple HTML tables in it. Now, when I execute my program it only retrieves the data of the first table in the CSV file and not retrieving the other tables. My java class code is as follows.

```
   public static void parsingHTML() throws Exception {
        //tbodyElements = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

            Elements table = doc.getElementsByTag("table");

            if (table.isEmpty()) {
                throw new Exception("Table is not found");
            }

            elements = table.get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");

            for (Element trElement : elements) {
                trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
                tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
                File fold = new File("C:\\convertedCSV9.csv");
                fold.delete();
                File fnew = new File("C:\\convertedCSV9.csv");
                FileWriter sb = new FileWriter(fnew, true);
                //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" ");
                //String y = "<tr>";

                for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

                    //Element tdElement1 = it.next();
                    //final String content2 = tdElement1.text();
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        sb.append("\r\n");

                    }
                    for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Element tdElement2 = it.next();
                        final String content = tdElement2.text();

                        //stringjoiner.add(content);
                        //sb.append(formatData(content));
                        if (it2.hasNext()) {

                            sb.append(formatData(content));
                            sb.append("   ,   ");

                        }
                        if (!it.hasNext()) {
                            String content1 = content.replaceAll(",$", " ");
                            sb.append(formatData(content1));
                            //it2.next();

                        }
                        
                    }

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    sb.flush();
                    sb.close();

                }
                System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));

            }
        }
    }
```

What I analyze is that there is a loop which is only checking tr tds. So, after first table there is a style sheet on the HTML page. May be due to style sheet loop is breaking. I think that's the reason it is proceeding to the next table.

P.S: here's the link which I am trying to scrap
http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01

Comment: How about your loop which forces you to only look at 1 table? `for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {`

Comment: when I increase it to 'i<=2 or i<=5' it will run the same table for two times or what number I wrote.

Comment: Because you hard coded the table you want to look at. `elements = table.get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");` No matter how many times you loop you only ever look at the first table in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do just at the beginning of your code will not work:

```
// loop just once, why
for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    Elements table = doc.getElementsByTag("table");

    if (table.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("Table is not found");
    }
    elements = table.get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");
```

Here you loop just once, read all `table` elements and then process all `tr` elements for the **first** table you find. So even if you would loop more than once, you would always process the first `table`.

You will have to iterate all `table` elements, e.g.

```
for(Element table : doc.getElementsByTag("table")) {
    for (Element trElement : table.getElementsByTag("tr")) {
        // process "td"s and so on
    }
}
```

**Edit** Since you're having troubles with the code above, here's a more thorough example. Note that I'm using `Jsoup` to read and parse the HTML (you didn't specify what you are using)

```
Document doc = Jsoup
                 .connect("http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01")
                 .get();

for (Element table : doc.getElementsByTag("table")) {
    for (Element trElement : table.getElementsByTag("tr")) {
        // skip header "tr"s and process only data "tr"s
        if (trElement.hasClass("tab-data1")) {

            StringJoiner tdj = new StringJoiner(",");
            for (Element tdElement : trElement.getElementsByTag("td")) {
                tdj.add(tdElement.text());
            }

            System.out.println(tdj);
        }
    }
}
```

This will concat and print all data cells (those having the class `tab-data1`). You will still have to modify it to write to your `CSV` file though.

Note: in my tests this processes 21 `table`s, 243 `tr`s and 2634 `td`s.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Sir. Your code is working but still there is a problem that it is skipping first 16 tables from the page and bring the rest.

Comment: @AhmedTalha added another example to my answer